# How to use wait to iterate and append to a dataframe

Tags: python, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to make sense of how to append a list of stocks into a single dataframe.

Someone said I needed to use the wait statement (if I want to iterate using an append statement).  I think I have it setup right, but I can't even do a simple iteration

```
from concurrent.futures import wait, ALL_COMPLETED

import concurrent.futures
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import yfinance as yf

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)

end=datetime.date.today()
start=end - timedelta(weeks=104)

symbols = ['GOOG','CSCO']

def dl(stock):
    #sleep(randint(1, 5))
    #print(stock)
    return yf.download(stock, start=start, end=end).iloc[: , :5].dropna(axis=0, how='any')

futures = [pool.submit(dl, args) for args in symbols]
wait(futures, timeout=10, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)

#print(futures[1])
futures[0].result()

stocks=[]

for x in range(len(symbols)):
    print(x)
    stocks.append(futures[x].result())
    futures[x].result()
    
print(stocks)
```

So... if I do the following

```
stocks = []
# CHANGE IN THE BELOW LINE
for x in range(len(futures)):
    #print(x)
    stocks.append(futures[x].result())
    #futures[x].result()

print(stocks)
```

It will print, but then it is two blocks of 502 rows each... and I want a single dataframe (i.e. 1004 rows).  I was able to accomplish this same behaviour before without using wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from concurrent.futures import wait, ALL_COMPLETED

import concurrent.futures
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import yfinance as yf

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)

end = datetime.date.today()
start = end - timedelta(weeks=104)

stocks = ['GOOG', 'CSCO']


def dl(stock):
    # sleep(randint(1, 5))
    # print(stock)
    return yf.download(stock, start=start, end=end).iloc[:, :5].dropna(axis=0, how='any')


futures = [pool.submit(dl, args) for args in stocks]
wait(futures, timeout=10, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)


# CHANGE IN THE BELOW LINE
stocks_data = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(0,len(stocks)):
    stocks_data = pd.concat([stocks_data,pd.DataFrame(futures[x].result())])
print(stocks_data.shape)
(1004, 5)
```

Comment: that doesn't run.  I tried len(futures) initially.  Did you actually run this?  In fact that is less functional than the original one which at least prints the values of x

Comment: Definitely  len(stocks) is a problems since before stocks = [].

Comment: my apologies... weird... I'm running this in jupyter lab and I get "KeyError: 'CSCO'".  I'll try in just jupyter

Comment: okay.  I'm going to edit my question.  I get something to work with your example

Comment: I need a single dataframe of 1004 rows... can you find the magic formula for that?

Comment: I just realized I set stocks and then I overwrite it with an empty array

Comment: thank you. idk why. Sometimes it runs and then it just doesn't and I keep getting a keyError

Comment: there is something that causes an error.  I'm not sure what it is.  Sometimes it runs, but most often it does not.

Comment: for example.  I commented out the for loop entirely and just try to print futures[0].result() and that is what results in a key error (as well as in the for loop)

Comment: I think that's a separate question.  I can get it to work occasionally. So I'll accept the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer so you can see what I went with... but I get a keyError about 90% of the time.  So I'm not sure if i'm using wait properly

Comment: the problem is threads suck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078568/trying-to-use-wait-with-concurrent-futures-to-append-to-a-dataframe-and-get-a-ke/66079008#66079008

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to Rafael Valero

but I figured I'd post the final code... I still get a "keyerror" more often than not, but occassionally the whole dataframe is populated

```
from concurrent.futures import wait, ALL_COMPLETED

import concurrent.futures
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)

end = datetime.date.today()
start = end - timedelta(weeks=104)

stocks = ['GOOG', 'CSCO']


def dl(stock):
    return yf.download(stock, start=start, end=end).iloc[:, :5].dropna(axis=0, how='any')


futures = [pool.submit(dl, args) for args in stocks]
wait(futures, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)

stocks_data = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(0,len(stocks)):
    prices = pd.DataFrame(futures[x].result())
    prices['Symbol'] = stocks[x]
    stocks_data = pd.concat([stocks_data,prices])

print(stocks_data)
```