# Trying to use wait with concurrent futures to append to a dataframe and get a keyerror about 90% of the time

Tags: python, keyerror, concurrent.futures

I get a key error specifically on futures[x].result() more often than not and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Maybe I'm not using wait properly?

```
from concurrent.futures import wait, ALL_COMPLETED

import concurrent.futures
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)

end = datetime.date.today()
start = end - timedelta(weeks=104)

stocks = ['GOOG', 'CSCO']


def dl(stock):
    return yf.download(stock, start=start, end=end).iloc[:, :5].dropna(axis=0, how='any')


futures = [pool.submit(dl, args) for args in stocks]
wait(futures, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)

stocks_data = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(0,len(stocks)):
    prices = pd.DataFrame(futures[x].result())
    prices['Symbol'] = stocks[x]
    stocks_data = pd.concat([stocks_data,prices])

print(stocks_data)
```

here's the (stack) error I get

I don't really have any more details to add other than this error but it's asking me to specify additional comments, so here I am filling in space so I can provide the stack trace

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-3da302790b49> in <module>
     24 stocks_data = pd.DataFrame()
     25 for x in range(0,len(stocks)):
---> 26     prices = pd.DataFrame(futures[x].result())
     27     prices['Symbol'] = stocks[x]
     28     stocks_data = pd.concat([stocks_data,prices])

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    423                 raise CancelledError()
    424             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 425                 return self.__get_result()
    426 
    427             self._condition.wait(timeout)

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py in run(self)
     54 
     55         try:
---> 56             result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     57         except BaseException as exc:
     58             self.future.set_exception(exc)

<ipython-input-160-3da302790b49> in dl(stock)
     16 
     17 def dl(stock):
---> 18     return yf.download(stock, start=start, end=end).iloc[:, :5].dropna(axis=0, how='any')
     19 
     20 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yfinance/multi.py in download(tickers, start, end, actions, threads, group_by, auto_adjust, back_adjust, progress, period, interval, prepost, proxy, rounding, **kwargs)
    117 
    118     if len(tickers) == 1:
--> 119         return shared._DFS[tickers[0]]
    120 
    121     try:

KeyError: 'CSCO'
```

Comment: If you only get a keyerror 90% of the time, it suggests something is occasionally failing (or perhaps timing out). Maybe try looping over the return values of [as_completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed). Showing a stack trace would be helpful as well.

Comment: added what I believe is the stack trace

Comment: The stack trace suggests you are passing an invalid ticker. Have you tried calling `yf.download` without any use of futures to prove that those calls work?

Comment: I was able to resolve it using an answer I posted here (something to do with threads)

Answer (score -2):

looks like threads suck (I read I should be using processes and not threads somewhere)

```
from concurrent.futures import wait, ALL_COMPLETED

import concurrent.futures
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

#pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)
pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()

end = datetime.date.today()
start = end - timedelta(weeks=104)

stocks = ['GOOG', 'CSCO']


def dl(stock):
    return yf.download(stock, start=start, end=end).iloc[:, :5].dropna(axis=0, how='any')

futures = [pool.submit(dl, args) for args in stocks]
wait(futures, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)

stocks_data = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(0,len(stocks)):
    prices = pd.DataFrame(futures[x].result())
    prices['Symbol'] = stocks[x]
    stocks_data = pd.concat([stocks_data,prices])

print(stocks_data)
```